# Is there a way to see object names in debug view hierarchy?

Tags: xcode, debugging, iboutlet

The `debug view hierarchy` is a great way to view they different layers that make up the `UI`, but as far as I can't tell there is no way to see what outlet reference names the objects have. They are simply referred to as what type of object they are. For example, a button is just refered to as `UIButton` rather than the name of the outlet. Yes, it's possible to see in what `viewController` it resides, but it' not foolprof and it can still be very hard to track down certain objects.

So, is there a way to see what the reference outlets of the objects are called?

Comment: `UIView.accessibilityIdentifier` does the trick.

Comment: @DawnSong can you please add that as an answer?

Comment: @pkamb I added an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is not (unfortunately).

The information is not maintained at runtime to my knowledge, so you also **won't** be able to use lldb from Xcode's console to figure it out.

Probably worth a feature request to Apple!
https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/

Comment: Ah, thanks! Agreed. View hierarchy would be a great tool if only this feature existed.

Answer (score 7):

`UIView.accessibilityIdentifier` does that trick.

For `NSLayoutConstraints`, its description in warning log (or `po constraint`) contains more details after set `UIView.accessibilityIdentifer`.
Before set `accessibilityIdentifier`, it's something like

> <NSLayoutConstraint: 0x6000037766c0 UILayoutGuide: 0x600002d6c620'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.trailing == UILabel: 0x7fee70712780.trailing + 132   (active)>

After set `accessiblityIdentifier`,

> <NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000037766c0 UILayoutGuide:0x600002d6c620'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.trailing == First-ID.trailing + 132   (active, names: First-ID:0x7fee70712780 )>

For **view debugger**, you can check `accessibilityIdentifier` as follows

[image]